# Getting the phone number onclick (JavaScript) does not work with a custom function in R

Tags: javascript, r, rselenium

I am trying to get the phone number onclick from https://www.europages.co.uk/WASTA-KONSERVEN-FISCHL-GMBH-CO-KG/DEU476016-00101.html. The following code works:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
#library(data.table)
library(RSelenium)

url <- "https://www.europages.co.uk/WASTA-KONSERVEN-FISCHL-GMBH-CO-KG/DEU476016-00101.html"
remDr <- remoteDriver( port = 4445L, browser = "firefox")
remDr$open(silent=TRUE)
remDr$navigate(url)
xp <- "//div[@class='click-tel icon icon-telephone']"
element <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', xp)
element$clickElement()
page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
page_source %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(".info-tel-num") %>% html_text()

# [1] "+49 854 79 60 10"
```

However, this does not work (only gives a blank output):

```
phone <- function(url){
  url <- url
  remDr$navigate(url)
  xp <- "//div[@class='click-tel icon icon-telephone']"
  element <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', xp)
  element$clickElement()
  page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  page_source %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(".info-tel-num") %>% 
  html_text()
}

phone(url)
```

Anyone can help explain why this is happening?